# Correct approach for selecting and calculating welding parameters - MAG welding of carbon steel

Tags: steel, welding

What would be correct approach for selecting welding parameters for MAG (Metal Arc Welding) welding of carbon steel.
How to select information that will go in WPS (Welding Procedure Specification) ?
Is there mathematical approach for parameters determination ?
What step will one take to do so ?

*Terminology used is European.*

Comment: What needs to be welded? What support is needed? Will it need a backing plate? Will it be achieved in one pass? If multiple passes, what clean & prep needed? Terminology is European.

Comment: Hello Solar Mike, the question is general. There is no specific situation. I know that all those factors will influence welding parameters selection but general answer with some example will also be good. Mostly Voltage and Wire Speed determination is my focus.

Comment: Get a book on welding.

Comment: You are eventually going to also need a PQR.

Comment: I guess you mean  SMAW , aka  "stick". Continuous wire feeds are more common today .

Answer (score 0):

Use the welding wire/ electrode manufacturer guidelines to choose welding parameters. As a welding engineer, I have experience using different welding process so I know what parameters best suits me. Also you can use trial method using scrap material to find suitable welding parameters.